# In xamarin.form How we can send sms with xamarin.form?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new to xamarin.form, I want to send sms automatically to phone numbers. Is there any free solution? I am working on a simple project.

Answer (score 3):

To send Messages in Xamarin.Forms you need to use **`Xamarin.Essentials`** plugin from nuget package manager

Code to send Message

```
public async Task SendSms(string messageText, string recipient)
{
    var message = new SmsMessage(messageText, new []{ recipient });
    await Sms.ComposeAsync(message);
}
```

For more information visit 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/sms

Answer (score 0):

Add Xamarin.Essentials in you nuget package and try the following code:

```
public async Task SendSms(string messageText, string recipient) 
{
    try
    {
        var message = new SmsMessage(messageText, new []{ recipient });
        await Sms.ComposeAsync(message);
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
    {
        // Sms is not supported on this device.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Other error has occurred.
    }
}
```

if you have to send to multiple recipients, change the parameter "string recipient" to an array of recipients "string[] recipients".
Let me know if you need further help on this.